# Privileges not being updated

Tags: postgresql

After running

```
db=> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO userx;
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_stat_statements"
GRANT
```

I tried to

```
drop trigger t_table on tablex;
```

I got this result

```
[42501] ERROR: must be owner of relation tablex
```

This is everything I ran to change my privileges:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE dbx to userx;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public to userx;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO userx;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO userx;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO userx;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCES TO userx;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTIONS TO userx;
```

What could I be possibly be missing? could WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_stat_statements" mean something or is it stopping at that table and not adding the privileges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the error message says, only the table owner (and a superuser) can do that.

The `TRIGGER` privilege allows you to *create* a trigger on the table, but not to *drop* one.

Ownership is not a privilege you can grant; you have to use `ALTER TABLE ... OWNER TO ...` for that.